# Solid color of Data Bar in Excel disappears

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

A strange thing is happening in the excel spreadsheet. I have the Data Bar (conditional formatting) applied on a column and I set a solid color for it, BUT after save the spreadsheet I close it and when I open it again the bars get gradient/gradual color!!!! Does anyone know why this is happening????

The first picture are the bars set with a solid blue color, I save and close the spreadsheet, then I open the spreadsheet and the bars are gradient/gradual color (second image)

[image]

Comment: Show us a before and after pic, it's hard to understand what you are referring to.

Comment: Hi Dave, I edited the post and upload the images now

Comment: It's really, really strange, I've never seen that. I will try to save in another computer and see what happen. I created these bars in the same Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. The file was saved as Excel 97-2003 and this is not compatible with it. I just saved as the newest Excel format to solve the problem.